# Consume a web service with AFNetworking 2

Tags: objective-c, web-services, afnetworking-2

I am trying consume a web serivce in an iOS project. I use AFNetworking for that. However current version is 2.x but I found only example code with 1.x version:

```
- (IBAction)loginButtonPressed {        
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://localhost/ws/"];


    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    [httpClient defaultValueForHeader:@"Accept"];

    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"tester", "nameField", 
                            nil];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" 
          path:@"https://localhost/ws/hello" parameters:params];

    //Add your request object to an AFHTTPRequestOperation
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] 
                                      initWithRequest:request] autorelease];

    [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:
      ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, 
      id responseObject) {
        NSString *response = [operation responseString];
        NSLog(@"response: [%@]",response);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [operation error]);
    }];

    //call start on your request operation
    [operation start];
    [httpClient release];
}
```

I don't know how to convert 'AFHTTPClient ' to 'AFHTTPRequestOperationManager' or 'AFHTTPRequestOperation'

I tried googling during 2 days however there are no any result I can use.

The service will received the 'name' and return a string : 'hello, name !'

**UPDATE 1**

I tried code bellow:

`AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"name": @"tester"};
    [manager POST:@"http://localhost/wp/?wsdl" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];`

and get eror:

`Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x8ae1f00 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}`

Please give me some advice.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it !

**Problem:**

Server is using nuSOAP. I change to another web serivce that return JSON and now client can consume web service pefectly.